# What is the best method to determine a trig ratio for a specific value?

Tags: trigonometry

I need to determine tangent of theta at a value at 2, for example.  It needs to be generic in that the value I'm looking for will change.  It only needs 1/10 precision but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: You need to describe with a lot more detail what it is you want to compute. "Tangent of theta at a value at 2" does not make much sense to me without further explanation.

Comment: ... unless, that is, you simply want to compute $\tan(2)$? For that you either get a computer/calculator to do it for you, or you look it up in a table. (If for some reason you're stuck to pencil and paper and no trig tables, you _could_ approximate the sine and cosine from their power series and divide, but it's hard to imagine a realistic situation where you would need that).

Comment: At what value of theta does tangent equal 2.  I don't know how else to describe it.  I'm creating a graph that displays a tangent curve and the boundary conditions change so I need to be able to calculate when it crosses those boundary conditions.

Comment: IOW - tan(theta)=2  solve for theta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clarified in comments that you want to find a $\theta$ such that $\tan(\theta) = 2$.

This is a task that can't really be broken down into simpler subtasks -- instead the solution has been given a name of its own: the **arctangent** of $2$, which you can ask a computer or calculator to find for you.

$$ \arctan(y)\text{ means the }\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)\text{ such that }\tan\theta=y $$

In programming languages the arctangent function is usually spelled `atan`; scientific calculators commonly use the symbol $\tan^{-1}$.

In a programming language, remember that `atan` will (almost always) give you $\theta$ in *radians*; if you need it in degrees you have to convert the result by multiplying by $\frac{180}{\pi}$.

The output will not be the *only* $\theta$ that gives $\tan\theta=2$; you can add or subtract any integer multiple of $\pi$ (or $180^\circ$) without changing its tangent.

Comment: Outstanding answer,  Thank you